# How to deploy Spring Cloud Data Flow on AWS EKS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-dataflow, amazon-eks

Are there any document for deploying Spring Cloud Data Flow on AWS EKS? I am looking for example or guide video about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no special instructions for running SCDF on EKS or any other K8s distribution. As far as you have a K8s cluster and the necessary service accounts, you will be able to provision SCDF on a given namespace.

You can either use the release-tagged [deployment YAMLs](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/) directly or the SCDF's Bitnami [Helm chart](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/). Depending on your customization needs, you'll find the deployment YAMLs more flexible, though.

Comment: So is that impossible for research about my approach?